# Compulsory review requests with review board or gerrit

Tags: git, gerrit, review-board

I just set up review board on git, also used the pre-commit hook scripts in git for sending review request to review board.
But it seems that there is no way to force all developers to send review request before pushing their code to a git remote server.

Can I do this using review board with git?  Also, I never tried gerrit, could it do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Review Board.  Gerrit allows you to force code to go through review before it can be merged in and pushed to remote servers, so yes it can do this.